# Creating anonymous view actions in Eclipse e4

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, e4

I am trying to create a new view using Eclipse e4 (my product is RCP 3.x based, but now updated to use the Legacye4.xmi). In the past when I wanted to create a toolbar action to interact with internal view state I would do something like this;

```
private TableViewer viewer;
private IAction doSomething;

private void makeActions() {
  doSomething = new Action() {
    public void run() {
      // Do something e.e.g with a table viewer
      tableViewer.getXXXX();
    }
  }
  getViewSite().getActionsBars().getToolBarManager().add(doSomething);
}
```

How can I achieve the same thing using e4 APIs?

As far as I can tell I now need to register a command and hook up a handler in plugin.xml/fragment.e4xmi but this approach only works on separate classes, not inner classes. I have found something that looks promising [here](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=282692). However I do not whether this is registering the handler just for the view or globally, or whether the handler needs deactivating/reactivating on part changes.

Comment: Are you still declaring the view using the 3.x method? All the 3.x stuff still works when you do that.

Comment: I am registering the view via the org.eclipse.ui.views/e4View and I am using the @PostContruct etc. annotations rather than extending ViewPart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an e4 view you normally declare the view tool bar items in the fragment.e4xmi in the ToolBar section of the Part.

You can use 'Handled Tool Item' in which you have to declare a 'command' and a 'handler', or you can use 'Direct Tool Item' in which case you just specify the class to call.

Add example handler execute method might be:

```java
@Execute
public void execute(MPart part)
{
  MyViewClass view = (MyViewClass)part.getObject();

  ... call view methods
}
```

Comment: How would you get access to the internal state this way?

Comment: You will need to provide methods in your view class that the handler can call. Added example handler